# Como apagar conteúdo Html completo?

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5, ajax

Eu estou fazendo um chat utilizando PHP, JavaScript, Ajax e HTML. Eu sei que não é a melhor opção, mas eu optei por criar um arquivo html `log.html` que armazena todas as mensagens e é carregado pelo meu arquivo PHP `index.php`. Todas as mensagens são enviadas ao log através do arquivo `post.php`. Eu preciso apagar todas as mensagens, ou seja, apagar todo o conteúdo do html presente no `log.html` em um determinado horário. Como  posso fazer isso? Segue o código dos arquivos.

### Index.php

```
/* Tentando apagar o conteúdo do arquivo */
$var = date('H:i:s');
if ($var == '02:00:00') {
    $fp = fopen("log.html", 'w');
    fwrite($fp, "");
    fclose($fp);
}

<!-- Dentro do HTML da página -->
<div class="chatlogs">
    <!--    mensagens vem pra cá     -->
</div>
<!-- mensagem que será enviada -->
<form class="chat-form" name="message" action="">
    <textarea name="usermsg" id="usermsg"></textarea>
    <button name="submitmsg" type="submit" id="submitmsg"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
</form>
```

```
// JS && Ajax da página
function loadLog() {
    var a = $(".chatlogs").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
    $.ajax({
        url: "log.html",
        cache: !1,
        success: function(t) {
            $(".chatlogs").html(t);
            var o = $(".chatlogs").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
            a < o && $(".chatlogs").animate({
                scrollTop: o
            }, "normal")
        }
    })
}
$(document).ready(function() {}), $("#submitmsg").click(function() {
    var t = $("#usermsg").val();
    return $.post("post.php", {
        text: t
    }), $("#usermsg").attr("value", ""), !1
}), setInterval(loadLog, 1e3);
```

### Post.php

```
<?php
    /* Envio da mensagem para o log.html */
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['usuarioUsuario'])){
        $text = $_POST['text'];
        $fp = fopen("log.html", 'a');
        if ($_SESSION["usuarioNivel"] == 9) {
            fwrite($fp, "<div class='chat self'><div class='user-photo'><img src='../../dist/img/perfil/" . $_SESSION['usuarioImagem'] . "'></div><p class='chat-message'><span class='user'>~".$_SESSION['usuarioUsuario']."</span>".stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($text))." <span class='hora'>".date("g:i A")."</span><br></p></div>");
        } else {
            fwrite($fp, "<div class='chat friend'><div class='user-photo'><img src='../../dist/img/perfil/" . $_SESSION['usuarioImagem'] . "'></div><p class='chat-message'><span class='user'>~".$_SESSION['usuarioUsuario']."</span>".stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($text))." <span class='hora'>".date("g:i A")."</span><br></p></div>");
        }
    fclose($fp);
    }
?>
```

Como eu apago todo o conteúdo do `log.html` em um determinado horário sem precisar de uma interação do usuário?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Apagar

```
$var = date('H:i:s');
if (strtotime($var) < strtotime('09:34:00') && strtotime($var) > strtotime('15:00:00')) {
    $fp = fopen("log.html", 'w');
    fwrite($fp, "");
    fclose($fp);
}
```

esse `strtotime()` reduz a hora a "int" e apos isso ele verifica um horário para fazer o apagamento mas indico por um tempo de distancia para caso haja algum atraso não cancelar seu apagamento, você pode por uma `cornjob` se quiser automatico...

## Apagar /cornjob

```
    $fp = fopen("log.html", 'w');
    fwrite($fp, "");
    fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Funciona, porém precisa de reload na página. Mas eu queria que não houvesse a necessidade de fazer uma requisição da página, ou seja, o usuário não deve dar um reload na página para que o log seja apagado. Eu gostaria que o log fosse apagado sem que houvesse interação em um horário (às 02:00 am).

Comment: CORNJOB entao para fazer automatico

Comment: http://blog.thiagobelem.net/o-que-sao-e-como-usar-as-cron-jobs ou ce usar cpainel procure por cornjob cpanel

Comment: você pode ate remover o if se for por cornjob

Comment: caso esteja solucionado o problema, marca como valida a resposta, para ficar como problema solucionado para os próximos